# JavaScript onkeyup camelcase vs lowercase

Tags: javascript

I do not seem to find what version of a "onkeyup" is correct:

camelcase: **onKeyUp**

or

lowercase: **onkeyup**

[UPDATE]  http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html mentions:

"Attribute names are always case-insensitive."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTML isn't case sensitive. So either are fine if they are in the HTML element, like so:

```
<div onkeyup='alert()'></div>
```

However, JavaScript is case sensitive. Only lower case will work there:

```
document.getElementById('div').addEventListener('keyup', function (){
    someCode();
}, false);
```

Answer (score 2):

`onkeyup` is correct, `onKeyUp` works because HTML is case insensitive. (XHTML is case sensitive so you should use `onkeyup` as the attribute.)

Answer (score 0):

The lower case version is correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
onkeyup
```

Refer - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeyup.asp